# Effects by ledger endpoint never returns any effects

Tags: horizon, effects

Is the *effects by ledger* endpoint broken or not yet implemented?

I imagine ledgers contain many events, but whichever I check there are [no effects](https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers/1/effects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were [no transactions](https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers/1/transactions) in ledger #1 so there are also no effects.

Comment: I can't find effects in any ledger. https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers/999/effects

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to check more recent ledgers. https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers/16225999/effects